# Login page won't display unless PHP code is removed

Tags: php, mysql, html, mamp

I've been following a few examples online to setup a user registration and login system with PHP+MySQL.

I have registration working fine, but my login.php page won't display. It is a simple html form. The form displays when I remove the PHP code but when I put the code back in I just get a blank white page.

This is the PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("db.php"); 
if (isset($_POST['username'] && isset($_POST['password'])) 
{     
user_login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']); 
} 
?>
```

I had this happen before due to a syntax error but can't see any here. Any ideas?

Comment: If you look at the source of the 'blank white page' what do you see?

Comment: is there an error in the db.php file being masked? Does this file work elsewhere / standalone? Are we assuming "user_login()" is defined therein?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isset($_POST['username']` isn't closed.

The code should be:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("db.php"); 
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) 
{     
user_login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']); 
} 
?>
```

However, PHP usually shows you an error if you do something like this. Your php.ini settings have probably suppressed errors, which is why there is a blank page

IMO, for development it's not a great idea to have errors turned off. It's a good idea on a live site, but not during development.

Comment: Thanks, surprised I didn't notice that. Good tip on the error settings too. It was displaying some errors earlier but I guess I haven't turned them all on.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing parenthesis at the end of the `if` line, I think.